# Firebase Real time database won't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed every process in [Getting started with firebase on the web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1D0_wFlXgo&index=9&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX)
video tutorial. And this is the code I wrote after watching the tutorial.

```
<h1 id="one"></h1>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCMhmAMbUwmZLQFG9EZLgnbmOJVabdfNvU",
    authDomain: "test-24e84.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-24e84.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "test-24e84.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var one = document.getElementsById('one');
  var dbref = firebase.database().ref().child('text');
  dbref.on('value', snap => one.innerText = snap.val());
</script>
```

After writing the code, I executed the html file in my chrome browser. However,I could not see any text on my screen.(It was just blank with no difference)

What Is wrong? How can i make code running?

Answer (score 3):

It fails because `document.getElementsById` is not a function; it's `document.getElementById`.